# How to convert a simple JavaScript function into TypeScript function?

Tags: javascript, typescript, function

I'm Java developer and I started learning TypeScript for frontend. And I have a very simple piece of JavaScript code and I want to convert it to TypeScript code.

This is the JavaScript code:

```
let numbers = [123, 234, 345, 456, 567];
let names = ['Alex', 'Bree', 'Cara', 'Cole', 'Devon', 'Riley'];

let bigA = numbers.filter(function(item)) {
    return item > 300;
}
```

And here is the TypeScript code:

```
let numbers: number[] = [123, 234, 345, 456, 567];
let names: string[] = ['Alex', 'Bree', 'Cara', 'Cole', 'Devon', 'Riley'];

let big: number[] = numbers.filter(function(item)) {
    return item > 300;
}
```

But there is an error for item: "Binding element 'item' implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7031)
", but it's not working if I put `return item: number > 300;`

I don't want to use this style `let big: number[] = numbers.filter((item) => item > 300);`

Do you know how to resolve it? Thank you!

Comment: There's an extra parenthesis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have closed your brackets in the wrong place. The closing brackets will be in the last line:

[image: wrong code]

Try this (Right code):

```js
let numbers: number[] = [123, 234, 345, 456, 567];
let names: string[] = ['Alex', 'Bree', 'Cara', 'Cole', 'Devon', 'Riley'];

let bigA: number[] = numbers.filter(function(item: number){
    return item > 300;
})
```